# How to get selected row index by checkbox in angular 13

Tags: arrays, typescript, angular13

I am trying to add data to table2 from table1, So i have used data1 and data2 array object.

> If i click the checkbox from table 1 i want to add that object to
> data2.
> If i click the checkbox from table 2 i want to remove that
> object from data2.

I do not know how to get that selected row index by clicking the checkbox.
If anyone knows please help to find the solution.

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8dfjxs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

app.component.html:

```
    <h5 class="text-center">Table 1</h5>
<div class="table1">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let row of data">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
          <td (click)="row.isExpand = !row.isExpand">
            <i *ngIf="!row.isExpand" class="bi-chevron-right"></i>
            <i *ngIf="row.isExpand" class="bi-chevron-up"></i>
            {{ row.name }}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="row.isExpand">
          <td colspan="2">
            {{ row.expandData }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<button (click)="addSelectedRow()">Add Selected Row To The Table2</button>

<h5 class="text-center">Table 2</h5>
<div class="table2">
  <table class="table">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let row of data2">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="box" /></td>
          <td (click)="row.isExpand = !row.isExpand">
            <i *ngIf="!row.isExpand" class="bi-chevron-right"></i>
            <i *ngIf="row.isExpand" class="bi-chevron-up"></i>
            {{ row.name }}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="row.isExpand">
          <td colspan="2">
            {{ row.expandData }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<button (click)="removeSelectedRow()">
  Remove Selected Row From The Table2
</button>
```

app.component.ts:

```
 addSelectedRow(){
  let selectedRowIndexFromTable1 = ??//How to get selected row index?
  this.data2.push(this.data1[selectedRowIndexFromTable1]);
  }

  removeSelectedRow(){
  let selectedRowIndexFromTable2 = ??//How to get selected row index?
  this.data2.splice(this.data2[selectedRowIndexFromTable2]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you can make the following modifications to your code:

1. Add a new property `isSelected` to each object in `data` and `data2` arrays to keep track of whether the checkbox is selected or not.
2. Use the `[(ngModel)]` directive to bind the `isSelected` property to the checkbox in the template.
3. In the `addSelectedRow` and `removeSelectedRow` functions, use `Array.findIndex` to find the index of the selected row based on the `isSelected` property.

Here's the updated code:

app.component.ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface RowData {
  name: string;
  expandData: string;
  isExpand: boolean;
  isSelected: boolean; // Add isSelected property
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  data: RowData[] = [
    { name: 'Row 1', expandData: 'Details 1', isExpand: false, isSelected: false },
    { name: 'Row 2', expandData: 'Details 2', isExpand: false, isSelected: false },
    // Add more rows as needed
  ];

  data2: RowData[] = [
    { name: 'Row A', expandData: 'Details A', isExpand: false, isSelected: false },
    { name: 'Row B', expandData: 'Details B', isExpand: false, isSelected: false },
    // Add more rows as needed
  ];

  addSelectedRow() {
    const selectedRowIndexFromTable1 = this.data.findIndex((row) => row.isSelected);
    if (selectedRowIndexFromTable1 !== -1) {
      this.data2.push({ ...this.data[selectedRowIndexFromTable1], isSelected: false });
    }
  }

  removeSelectedRow() {
    const selectedRowIndexFromTable2 = this.data2.findIndex((row) => row.isSelected);
    if (selectedRowIndexFromTable2 !== -1) {
      this.data2.splice(selectedRowIndexFromTable2, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```html
<!-- Update the checkboxes to use [(ngModel)] -->
<td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="row.isSelected" /></td>
<!-- ... -->

<!-- Add a button to toggle selection in Table 1 -->
<button (click)="toggleSelectAll()">Select/Deselect All in Table1</button>
```

Don't forget to import `FormsModule` in your module to enable the use of `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: Multiple select is not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xhn6xg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html